# Direct algorithm for an integer program

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-programming

Let $p$ be a prime and let $h_1,h_2\in\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$ be integers.

Is there any direct algorithm to solve for following in polynomial in $\log p$ time?

$$\min (x_1-x_2)^2$$
$$x_1,x_2,k\in\mathbb Z$$
$$h_1^{x_1}-h_2^{x_2}=kp$$
$$0<x_1,x_2<p-1$$

> Actually if we know how to decide emptiness of following, then it suffices as we can use binary search over $a_i,b_i,c$ at $i\in\{1,2\}$:
>
> $$x_1,x_2,k\in\mathbb Z$$
> $$h_1^{x_1}-h_2^{x_2}=kp$$
> $$(x_1-x_2)^2<c$$
> $$0<a_1<x_1<b_1<p-1$$
> $$0<a_2<x_2<b_2<p-1$$

Comment: $x_1 = x_2 = p - 1$ gives $(x_1 - x_2)^2 = 0$. Do you want minimal positive value of $(x_1 - x_2)^2$?

Comment: yes thats what I meant. I could have phrased better.

Comment: This is trivially as hard as the discrete logarithm problem in $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$.

Comment: @Aurel: I doubt that. This problem has a trivial solution for many instances (see my answer below), and I do not see how it can help to solve the discrete logarithm problem.

Comment: @Turbo: You won't get a solution to DLP, but something like $x_1=x_2=\frac{p-1}2$, which is not even invertible modulo $\varphi(p)=p-1$.

Comment: I see what you are saying.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev How about if $p-1=2q$ and $q$ is a prime and we search in $0<a_i<x_i<b_i<q$ or $q<a_i<x_i<b_i<2q$ at $i\in\{1,2\}$?

Comment: @Turbo: I did not check the details, but accurately tightening things up it's very well possible that you'd end up with a problem of no less complexity as the discrete logarithm. Personally I do not see much sense in such reformulations of the known hard problems.

Comment: Yes I understand the problem remains hard without a way to check emptiness of the resulting region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extremely difficult non-linear integer programming problem. The difficulty consists in the restriction $h_1^{x_1}-h_2^{x_2}=kp$ which is hardly handled by known methods. I don't know any specialized soft to this end. Mathematica 14  easily solves it for

```
p = Prime[10^2]; SeedRandom[1234]; h1 = RandomChoice[Range[p - 1]];
h2 = RandomChoice[Range[p - 1]]; NMinimize[{(x1 - x2)^2, 
Mod[h1^x1 - h2^x2, p] == 0 && x1 \[Element] Integers && 
x2 \[Element] Integers && 0 < x1 && x1 < p - 1 && x2 > 0 && 
x2 < p - 1}, {x1, x2}] // Timing
```

> `{0.671875, {9., {x1 -> 192, x2 -> 195}}}`

with $p =541$.`SeedRandom[1234];` guaranties the reproducibility of randomly chosen  $h_1,h_2$ . Making use of options, one obtains

```
p = Prime[2*10^2]; SeedRandom[1234]; h1 = RandomChoice[Range[p - 1]]; 
h2 = RandomChoice[Range[p - 1]]; NMinimize[{(x1 - x2)^2, 
Mod[h1^x1 - h2^x2, p] == 0 && x1 \[Element] Integers && 
x2 \[Element] Integers && 0 < x1 && x1 < p - 1 && x2 > 0 && 
x2 < p - 1}, {x1, x2},  Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1, 
"SearchPoints" -> 150}, MaxIterations -> 2000] // Timing
```

> `{133.375, {23409., {x1 -> 936, x2 -> 783}}}`

with $p=1223$. My comp is not powerful and fails with `p=Prime[10^3]`(equals $7919$). The methods are described in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is trivial at least for a half of instances by simply taking $x_1=x_2=\frac{p-1}2$. This gives a solution when the orders of $h_1,h_2$ modulo $p$ divide $\frac{p-1}2$; or when both orders equal $p-1$.